# Measurability of a classical topological surface and its measure

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, differential-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

Let $\Sigma \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be a set with the following property: Given any $p\in \Sigma$, $\exists$ $W_p \subset_{\text{open}} \mathbb{R}^3$, $U_p \subset_{\text{open}} \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $p \in W_p$, and there exists a homeomorphism $\varphi_p: U_p \rightarrow W_p \cap \Sigma$ (Both having the subspace topology induced from usual topology of $\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R}^3$ respectively). In essence $\Sigma$ is a 'topological' surface. Regarding this definition I had 2 questions which I could not find online:

1. If $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ denotes the lebesgue sigma algebra in $\mathbb{R}^3$, is it true that $\Sigma \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ always?
2. Intuitively, it feels like a surface is essentially a collection of patches which are like deformed planar regions, and so should have $0$ volume. Then if $\Sigma$ is a surface such that $\Sigma \in  \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^3)$, then is it true that $m(\Sigma)=0?$ for any such surface? (where $m$ denotes the lebesgue measure)

It seems to me that if the surface has some differentiable structure (eg. regular surfaces) then the following properties should be true, as in locally I can use implicit function theorem and write it locally as a graph of a $\mathbb{R}$ valued continuous function; in that case we can most likely show that each patch has measure $0$ and by second countability/$\sigma$-finiteness of $\mathbb{R}^3$, the surface is measurable and has measure $0$, but what about the general case, in the sense allowing weird kind of pointy surfaces?

Comment: No on part (2) and yes on (1).

Comment: @MoisheKohan could you justify it with a proof/reference?

Comment: Yes, later.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part 1 is immediate once you understand the definitions involved (and there is no need to restrict to dimension 3). I will just leave you two hints:

(a) First prove that every closed subset of $\Bbb R^n$ belongs to the Borel sigma-algebra, hence, to the Lebesgue sigma-algebra. (You really just need to know what a sigma-algebra is and that products of open intervals belong to the Lebesgue sigma-algebra.)

(b) Prove that every (nonempty) $k$-dimensional topological submanifold $M$ of $\Bbb R^n$ can be expressed as a countable union of subsets homeomorphic to the closed unit disk $D^k$. If you have hard time with this, first verify that every subset of $\Bbb R^n$  satisfies the 2nd countability axiom (something that you typically learn in a general topology class).

Part 2 is trickier. One way to find examples of topological surfaces in $\Bbb R^3$ of positive 3-d Lebesgue measure is to start with an [Osgood curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osgood_curve) $C\subset \Bbb R^2$, which is a Jordan curve of positive 2-d Lebesgue measure. Now, take the direct product of $J$ with an open interval  and obtain a topological surface in $\Bbb R^3$ that has positive 3-d Lebesgue measure. The same construction will work, of course, in higher dimensions.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm missing something simple, but why is it that suppose I have a homeomorphism $\varphi: D^2 \rightarrow A$, where $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$, then A is measurable in R^3? How does the subspace topology in the set go back to the bigger set?

Comment: @RohanDidmishe: First, read the hints.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm able to resolve it; if I have a limit point $y$ of $A \in \mathbb{R}^3$ then I can select a sequence $y_n \rightarrow y$. But then $\varphi^{-1}(y_n)$ is a sequence in $D^2$, hence by Bolzano-Weierstrass Thm $\exists y_{n_k}$ such that $\varphi^{-1}(y_{n_k}) \rightarrow x$ for some $x$ which must belong to $D^2$ as it is closed. Then by continuity of $\varphi$, $y_{n_k} \rightarrow \varphi(x) = y$. Hence $A$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: Compact implies closed (in, say, metric spaces) is really a very basic result that you learn when taking a real analysis (or general topology) class (BW theorem is huge overkill). Ditto, compact is invariant under homeomorphisms.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I shall try to prove the rest myself.